# Find first non-zero in a numeric string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I have a `char(12)` column with data such as:

```
000000004012
000000615737
000000000012
000000000100
```

And I need to convert it to this:

```
4012
615737
12
100
```

My initial thought is to use string manipulation, such as CHARINDEX.  However, I would need to search from left-to-right for the first occurrence of `NOT 0`.  How can I accomplish this in SQL Server?

Comment: Please just don't store numeric data in text columns.

Comment: I didn't create the database, I just have to work with it.  Not really a viable option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By the way, why did you store tha data in `char`? but to answer your question, try this,

```
SELECT CAST(colName AS INT)
```

or

```
SELECT CAST('999999999999' AS NUMERIC(12,0))
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32a39/5)

Comment: No, I didn't create this database if that's what you're asking.  And I'm laughing at myself for making this more difficult than it really was.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 but I would never, ever, cast as NUMERIC without indicating precision and scale.

Comment: @TaylorKimmel oh i see, But i prefer `numeric` than `int` since its possible to have value of `12` 9's causing it to overflow.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks! as seen [here: Numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If we talk about numeric data, it is sufficient to do `cast(column as int)` or as any other numeric data type.